# "To continue using iCloud, confirm your MacBook Pro password" requested multiple times per week

Tags: mac, icloud, security, password, system-settings

In the last few weeks, my Intel MacBook Pro 15" 2018 running macOS Ventura 13.2.1 has been requesting its local password for using iCloud, which I think has happened in the past, but certainly not with this frequency: multiple times a week, almost daily.

This shows up in a notification, which opens the System Settings app and asks for my password, and then the action item disappears from the left menu of System Settings, as well as the notification. It doesn't appear like any kind of scam.

Is something incorrectly configured on my end, or just a new boneheaded policy from Apple to train users on frequently typing their passwords to get rid of notifications, ensuring they fall hook line and sinker for scams in the future?

Comment: I suggest you go to System Settings > iCloud and deliberately logout, then login again. Do you login to iCloud on other devices?